# Vim CursorLine transparent light

Tags: vim, colors

I have trouble understanding how the Vim color system works. I try to configure the color of my CursorLine with this code and the table below, but it doesn't work.

```
:highlight CursorLine ctermfg=White ctermbg=1 cterm=bold
```

https://github.com/guns/xterm-color-table.vim

When I put 1 for example, I have a blue color while the table says red.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the output you get for `:XtermColorTable` ?

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? The Windows console's indexed palette has a few colours switched around compared to most other implementations so using indices 0-15 is not portable. If you want "Red", use "Red" (or "red", casing doesn't matter).

Comment: I actually thought that the colors on the repository were the same for everyone. I didn't install the Plugin to check. Thanks for pointing this out to me.

Answer (score 0):

I actually thought that the colors on the repository were the same for everyone. I didn't install the Plugin to check.

I need to install the plugin myself to check the colors specific to my terminal.

Thanks comments for pointing this out to me.